# How can you tell when a creature can speak a language or just understand it?

Tags: pathfinder-1e

For example, the Unicorn entry in the bestiary says Languages: common, sylvan

Does that mean the unicorn can speak and understand both or just understand common but not speak it?

I thought I remembered reading something about this in a book but can't remember which one.

Answer (score 6):

**It'll say**

The format that gets used is this:

- If it just lists languages, the creature can speak, understand, and read the languages.
- If it says 'understands', the creature can understand and read the indicated languages.

Comment: thanks, I knew I saw it somewhere but I couldn't remember if it was in a rule section or right on the entries.  Really appreciate it!